# How to test Https listener with local host in Mule4

Tags: mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to test https rest service in my local machine. For this i have created one global https connector and set it to localhost. But when i run the project it says " KeyStore must be configured for server side SSL in configuration "

Comment: share the HTTP connector configuration, masking the passwords.

Answer (score 0):

If the request is inside Mule then you may ignore it inside http request configuration like this
[image]

See example here https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/HowToIgnoreInsecureCertificates.html

If it is in another application then it depends on it - here is good start how ti [export/import certificates](https://www.digicert.com/import-export-ssl-certificate.htm)